# Excel-VBA calling a Powerpoint Macro fails while running it directly on PowerPoint works fine

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

(Excel and PowerPoint 2011 for Mac)

I have a excel macro that opens a powerpoint and executes a macro. 
If I execute the powerpoint macro directly it works fine, but if I execute it from the excel macro call it fails with Run-time error '68': Device unavailable

It's before this loop:

```
Dim strfilee As String


mydir = ":tmp"
strpath = mydir & ":"
strfilee = Dir(strpath)  <--- Failing on this line


''''Loop through each file in the folder to find the one with the OS parameters

    i = 0

    Do While Len(strfilee) > 0
    cellplace = "A" & i

        If Right(strfilee, 11) = "params.pptx" Then
        lspace = InStr(1, strfilee, "_", vbTextCompare)
        target_name = Trim(Left(strfilee, lspace - 1))
        sc_file_name = "tmp" & ":" & strfilee

                With ActivePresentation
                    number_slides = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
                  End With
                ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile sc_file_name, number_slides


         End If
        strfilee = Dir
      i = i + 1

    Loop
```

Comment: So your path variable is being set to ":tmp:". I can't see how that works in either case. Shouldn't it be either a local drive reference e.g. "C:\tmp\" or a network location such as "\\myServer\tmp\". According to MSDN the Dir function takes the PathName parameter as "String expression that specifies a file name, directory or folder name, or drive volume label."

Comment: Hello JamieG, thanks for answering. :tmp is just a reference to the tmp folder in the actual folder where the presentation is located. I will try to change it to the global one to see if this can be the root cause. Thanks!

Comment: That fixed the issue. When you execute the macro directly on the Powerpoint, the relative path ":tmp:" works fine. If you want to call the powerpoint macro from excel, you must put the global route (activepresentation.path $":tmp:"

Comment: Cool. I posted that as the answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the fully qualified path when using the Dir function.